# Product position in top level category not working

Tags: products, category-products, position

Hi guys so basically I have the following structure

Cat A
  - Cat B
    - Products
  - Cat C
    - Products
  - Cat D
    - Products

When editing Cat A I have set a position for all the products inside under the "Category Products" tab.

When visiting Cat A frontend it shows all products, not sub-categories which is fine but the order is not by position when the dropdown is selected they are just random.

I echo'd out $_product->getCatIndexPosition(); which shows most of them are set to 1 and not what I have set backend.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to reindex your products?

You can easily do it in the admin of Magento but you might encounter timeout issues. By SSHing to your server, go to the shell directory and type in

```
php indexer.php reindexall
```

This will take a few minutes, depending of your catalog. I would clear the cache prior to this. Also, if you have a full page cache set on, don't forget to refresh it.

You may also set negative values for positions, to make sure they show first.

Hope it helps.